# How can I see the size of all documents in a database excluding design?

Tags: lotus-notes

I can see the size of the database in Database properties, Info tab. But this size includes the size of design elements (forms, views, framesets, etc).

Does Lotus Notes provide a way to get only size of the documents in database excluding the size of design elements?

Answer (score 1):

Make a design-only copy of the database for reference and record it's size. Then subtract that from the size of the actual database. But note: your result will include the size of your view indexes, and it's not clear to me whether you do or don't want that.

Comment: I am looking for only size of documents. Also something Lotus Notes would provide out of box which my users can directly see. But I don't think its possible.

Comment: Well, I think the idea is that size of documents isn't the only thing that matters.  What users really see is two things: the size of documents only, or the size of documents + the view index data associated with those documents.

Answer (score 0):

The NotesDocument object has a field called "Size" which will return the value in bytes of a particular documents size.

Link to Javascript call (which has links to LotusScript / Java).

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.api.doc/r_domino_Document_Size.html

Size is subjective though. While it will tell you the size of the document, if the attachments are compressed then it will report the compressed size. Also DAOS may be a factor as well.

Comment: Actually I am looking for a solution which does not involve any code to be written. Like in Info tab of Database properties it shows `Disk space` which includes size of documents and design elements. Is their any place where I can see just the size of all documents in database?

Comment: No, wothout programming this is not possible. For a one time job you could create a view (not to complex to do) showing all documents (without response hierarchy) and one column containing the document size (can be selected without writing code), with a total... This is the least complex solution I can think of.

Answer (score -1):

Why would you ever need to know that info? You can find it for individual docs through document properties, but I can't imagine any situation where you'd need to know it for all the documents. You could have an all documents view where one of the columns was `doc.getSize().toFixed()` and then sum them all up, but document size isn't useful to know for anything.

```
var doc:NotesDocument = currentDocument.getDocument();
return "The current document uses " + doc.getSize().toFixed() + " bytes"
```

Source: [Lotus Domino Designer 8.5.3 docs](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.api.doc/r_domino_Document_Size.html) at IBM Knowledge Center

Comment: If you are referring to [Java syntax](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/rnext/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/ed67577316b18b8d85256c54004dc106?OpenDocument) `doc.getSize()`, then it returns an `int` variable. What is the `toFixed()` method you are calling on `int`?

Comment: IBM Knowledge Center had a bunch of examples and they use .toFixed in javascript examples because it converts it to text. For java you could just use doc.getSize(). Personally I'd probably use formula language and use @DocLength

Comment: Any reference links verifying your claim?

Comment: Which claim don't you believe?

Comment: I am not aware of any JS syntax `doc.getSize().toFixed()` to get document size in Lotus Notes. I haven't come across a way to access the `NotesDocument` object in JS. If you have any examples prove otherwise then do let me know. It would be a learning for me.

Comment: See the edit in my answer above.

Comment: Ahh... So you were referring to server-side JS!